# CardView with data from local Database, not displaying in fragment

Tags: java, android, adapter

I want to create a fragment where I display a CardView containing data fetched from a database that is currently on the localhost server.It is only showing a blank fragment screen; nothing is being displayed.

Here is the Fragment where the CardView is supposed to be displayed (UserFindFundiFragment):

```
package com.example.fundijava;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.text.StringKt;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.textclassifier.TextLinks;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class UserFindFundiFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FindFundiAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<FundiProfile> fundiProfileArrayList;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.100.43/MyFundiApp/getFundiProfiles.php";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_find_fundi, container, false);
//        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.userFindFundiRecyclerView);
//        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
//
//        adapter = new FindFundiAdapter();
//        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//
//        return view;

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_find_fundi, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.userFindFundiRecyclerView); //Specifying in which recycler view the info fetched will be displayed
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1); //Creating a vertical grid layout in this fragment
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        fundiProfileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Initialize adapter with an empty ArrayList
        adapter = new FindFundiAdapter(getContext(), fundiProfileArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getFundiProfiles();

//        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_find_fundi, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    private void getFundiProfiles() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, BASE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { //Loop through all the elements
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String fundiProfileID = jsonObject.getString("fundiProfileID");
                                String fundiID = jsonObject.getString("fundiID");
                                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                String gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                String profession = jsonObject.getString("profession");
                                String county = jsonObject.getString("county");
                                String experience = jsonObject.getString("experience");
                                Boolean availability = jsonObject.getBoolean("availability");
                                String package_1 = jsonObject.getString("package_1");
                                Integer package_1_cost = jsonObject.getInt("package_1_cost");
                                String package_2 = jsonObject.getString("package_2");
                                Integer package_2_cost = jsonObject.getInt("package_2_cost");
                                String package_3 = jsonObject.getString("package_3");
                                Integer package_3_cost = jsonObject.getInt("package_3_cost");
                                String package_4 = jsonObject.getString("package_4");
                                Integer package_4_cost = jsonObject.getInt("package_4_cost");


                                FundiProfile fundiProfile = new FundiProfile(
                                        fundiProfileID,
                                        fundiID,
                                        name,
                                        gender,
                                        profession,
                                        county,
                                        experience,
                                        availability,
                                        package_1,
                                        package_2,
                                        package_3,
                                        package_4,
                                        package_1_cost,
                                        package_2_cost,
                                        package_3_cost,
                                        package_4_cost
                                );

                                fundiProfileArrayList.add(fundiProfile);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException exception) {

                        }

                        // Notify the adapter that the data set has changed
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml for the UserFindFundiFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".UserFindFundiFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/userFindFundiRecyclerView"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fundi_profile_card"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the FindFundiAdapter:

```
package com.example.fundijava;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindFundiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FindFundiAdapter.FindFundiViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<FundiProfile> fundiProfileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FindFundiAdapter(Context context, List<FundiProfile> fundiProfileArrayList) {
//        Constructor
        this.context = context;
        this.fundiProfileArrayList = fundiProfileArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FindFundiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//        When the fragment is called on by the parent, this will inflate the card view inside the relevant frame layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fundi_profile_card, parent, false);
        return new FindFundiViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFundiViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final FundiProfile fundiProfile = fundiProfileArrayList.get(position);

        //Declaring the view holders whose contents should be updated
        holder.textViewfundiId.setText(fundiProfile.getFundiID());
        holder.textViewfundiname.setText(fundiProfile.getName());
        holder.textViewfundigender.setText(fundiProfile.getGender());
        holder.textViewfundiprofession.setText(fundiProfile.getProfession());
        holder.textViewfundicounty.setText(fundiProfile.getCounty());
        holder.textViewfundiexperience.setText(fundiProfile.getExperience());
        holder.textViewfundiavailability.setText(fundiProfile.getAvailability().toString());
        holder.textViewpackage1.setText(fundiProfile.getPackage_1());
        holder.textViewpackage1cost.setText("Ksh "+ fundiProfile.getPackage_1_cost());;
        holder.textViewpackage2.setText(fundiProfile.getPackage_2());
        holder.textViewpackage2cost.setText("Ksh "+ fundiProfile.getPackage_2_cost());
        holder.textViewpackage3.setText(fundiProfile.getPackage_3());
        holder.textviewpackage3cost.setText("Ksh "+ fundiProfile.getPackage_3_cost());
        holder.textViewpackage4.setText(fundiProfile.getPackage_4());
        holder.textViewpackage4cost.setText("Ksh "+ fundiProfile.getPackage_4_cost());

        holder.linearLayoutFundiProfileCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fundiFragmentContainer, new FundiNotificationsFragment()).commit();
//                Fragment fragment = new Fragment(context, UserFindFundiFragment.class);
//                fragment.startActivity(fragment);
//                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FundiActivity.class);
//                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fundiProfileArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class FindFundiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewfundiId;
        private TextView textViewfundiname;
        private TextView textViewfundiprofession;
        private TextView textViewfundigender;
        private TextView textViewfundicounty;
        private TextView textViewfundiexperience;
        private TextView textViewfundiavailability;
        private TextView textViewpackage1;
        private TextView textViewpackage1cost;
        private TextView textViewpackage2;
        private TextView textViewpackage2cost;
        private TextView textViewpackage3;
        private TextView textviewpackage3cost;
        private TextView textViewpackage4;
        private TextView textViewpackage4cost;

        private LinearLayout linearLayoutFundiProfileCard;
        public FindFundiViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

//            Declaring variables as and initialising them as the respective views in which queried fundi profile data will be displayed
            linearLayoutFundiProfileCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundiProfileContainer);

            textViewfundiId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundiID);
            textViewfundiname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundiname);
            textViewfundiprofession = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundiprofession);
            textViewfundigender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundigender);
            textViewfundicounty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundicounty);
            textViewfundiexperience = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundiexperience);
            textViewfundiavailability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundiavailability);
            textViewpackage1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage1);
            textViewpackage1cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage1cost);
            textViewpackage2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage2);
            textViewpackage2cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage2cost);
            textViewpackage3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage3);
            textviewpackage3cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage3cost);
            textViewpackage4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage4);
            textViewpackage4cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fundipackage4cost);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
package com.example.fundijava;

/*
* This is a class to represent a fundi profile. It will be used to define the profile attributes
* and class methods to retrieve data that will be displayed in the fundi profile card that will
* subsequently be displayed in the UserFindFundi fragment. */
public class FundiProfile {
    private String fundiProfileID, fundiID, name, gender, profession, county, experience, package_1, package_2, package_3, package_4;
    private Integer package_1_cost, package_2_cost, package_3_cost, package_4_cost;
    private Boolean availability;

    public FundiProfile (String fundiProfileID, String fundiID, String name, String gender,
                         String profession, String county, String experience, Boolean availability,
                         String package_1, String package_2, String package_3, String package_4,
                         Integer package_1_cost, Integer package_2_cost, Integer package_3_cost,
                         Integer package_4_cost) {
        this.fundiProfileID = fundiProfileID;
        this.fundiID = fundiID;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.county = county;
        this.experience = experience;
        this.availability = availability;
        this.package_1 = package_1;
        this.package_1_cost = package_1_cost;
        this.package_2 = package_2;
        this.package_2_cost = package_2_cost;
        this.package_3 = package_3;
        this.package_3_cost = package_3_cost;
        this.package_4 = package_4;
        this.package_4_cost = package_4_cost;
    }

    public String getFundiProfileID() { return fundiProfileID;}
    public void setFundiProfileID(String fundiProfileID) { this.fundiProfileID = fundiProfileID; }

    public String getFundiID() { return fundiID;}
    public void setFundiID(String fundiID) { this.fundiID = fundiID; }

    public String getName() { return name;}
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getGender() { return gender;}
    public void setGender(String gender) { this.gender = gender; }

    public String getProfession() { return profession;}
    public void setProfession(String profession) { this.profession = profession; }

    public String getCounty() { return county;}
    public void setCounty(String county) { this.county = county; }

    public String getExperience() { return experience;}
    public void setExperience(String experience) { this.experience = experience; }

    public Boolean getAvailability() { return availability;}
    public void setAvailability(Boolean availability) { this.availability = availability; }
    public String getPackage_1() { return package_1;}
    public void setPackage_1(String package_1) { this.package_1 = package_1; }

    public Integer getPackage_1_cost() { return package_1_cost;}
    public void setPackage_1_cost(Integer package_1_cost) { this.package_1_cost = package_1_cost; }

    public String getPackage_2() { return package_2;}
    public void setPackage_2(String package_2) { this.package_2 = package_2; }

    public Integer getPackage_2_cost() { return package_2_cost;}
    public void setPackage_2_cost(Integer package_2_cost) { this.package_2_cost = package_2_cost; }

    public String getPackage_3() { return package_3;}
    public void setPackage_3(String package_3) { this.package_3 = package_3; }

    public Integer getPackage_3_cost() { return package_3_cost;}
    public void setPackage_3_cost(Integer package_3_cost) { this.package_3_cost = package_3_cost; }

    public String getPackage_4() { return package_4;}
    public void setPackage_4(String package_4) { this.package_4 = package_4; }

    public Integer getPackage_4_cost() { return package_4_cost;}
    public void setPackage_4_cost(Integer package_4_cost) { this.package_4_cost = package_4_cost; }



}
```

Here is the CardView xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#C4DCD0D0"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fundiProfileContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="25sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fundiID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:text="FundiID 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fundiname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
            android:text="Name 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fundiavailability"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
            android:text="Availability"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundiprofession"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:text="Profession 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundigender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Gender 1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundicounty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="County 1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundiexperience"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Experience 1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage1cost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 1 Cost"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 2"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage2cost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 2 Cost"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 3"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage3cost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 3 cost"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 4"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fundipackage4cost"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
                    android:text="Package 4 cost"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I was expecting the cardview to be displayed in the UserFindFundiFragment,while containing data that has been retrieved from the database.